# R data table select with probability

Tags: r

I have the following R code

```
> z1 <- sample(9, 50, replace=T)
> z2 <- sample(10:100, 100, replace=T)
> z3 <- c(z1, z2)
> dt <- data.table(z3)
> dt
     z3
  1:  9
  2:  7
  3:  7
  4:  2
  5:  5
 ---   
146: 56
147: 91
148: 83
149: 72
150: 40
```

I want to select my training and test rows in my data table such that 60% of rows are training data. This is 60%*150 = 90

Out of these 90, I want to select 30 random rows from 0-9 and the remainder 60 random rows from 10 to 100.

Is it possible to use the data.table one liners to do this succintly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a one line solution. I'd do it like this:

```
test.inds <- c( sample( length(z1), 30 ), sample( length(z2), 60)+50 )
test.dt   <- dt[test.inds]
train.dt  <- dt[-test.inds]
```